# classic asp stop redirecting

Tags: asp-classic

I have an index.html file & a default.asp file (same directory)

and I want to access the index.html file only if domain/server name was entered e.g. www.cat.com if anything else was entered I want to display Response.Write('Page Not Found')

my default.asp file:

```
<% 

 If InStr( UCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),  UCase("cat.com") ) = 0 Then 
    Response.Write("Page Not Found") 
 End If 
%>
```

Reason I am doing this is because I am pointing multiple domains to the same directory.

Currently both domains gets redirected to the index.html file.

Is it possible to stop execution if other then cat.com was entered?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have both index.html _and_ default.asp?

Comment: default.asp will check what domain/server name was entered and show page not found/page 404 if it is wrong domain

Comment: Still explain why you have both.  Why not include the content of Index.html in default.asp and ditch index.html entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To invoke a 404 style behaviour in your code then use

```
Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
Response.End
```

However you can't block access to static content like .html files on the basis of the host name in the request.

Comment: I tried to put the 2 lines you provided in the IF condition and it is still redirects to the .html file... how would I show 404 page style?

Comment: @Ben: Your requirement is still very cloudy.  Perhaps you could beef up your question, explain the different scenarios and why you even have both files.  I assume that you've moved default.asp to the top of the default document list in IIS manager?

Comment: Hi Anthony, I have one hosting server and at the root I placed the code and two domains pointed to the root folder. All works perfectly, now I created another folder e.g. site2 folder at the root and placed some html files in it (e.g.index.html) so if user enters www.cat.com/site2/ (allow to view the index.html) and if the user uses second domain e.g. www.dog.com/site2/ I want to show the 404 error. I hope it makes sense what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: @Ben: yes it makes sense now.  On surface of it just stop using index.html use a default.asp inside the site2 folder.  That way you can include your server checking.  However surely you are look to prevent any access of content in site2 when the host name is www.dog.com.  Bottom line is you simply can't do this for static content.  I guess the you are doing this to prevent having to create a new root website for cost reasons?

Comment: I tried to use the default.asp file inside the site2 folder to check if its wrong servername then use the code you posted, but it doesnt work. and yes the reason I m doing this is cause of cost reasons, its a static html site and I dont really want to buy another host.

Comment: If it is not possible, I was wondering if you know, if possible, if I create 2 subfolders under the root, e.g. /proj1 & /proj2 flder and place the code inside. have default.asp at the root to check if its cat.com go to proj1 and if dog.com go to proj2 folder. I tried that & I can redirect to specific folder but it looks wired in the url. looks e.g cat.com/proj1/home.html or dog.com/proj2/home.html. Is it possible to hide the subfolder names in the URL? thanks so much for your help